# Dynamically add css class to span tag when text is set to "Completed" with Vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js, class

I have list of files ready to be uploaded with status "Waiting":

```html
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item" v-for="file in uploadedFiles">
    {{ file.fileName }}
    <span class="badge">{{file.uploadStatus}}</span>
    </li></ul>
```

when the upload status of the file changes to "Completed" i want to dynamically add class "badge-success" to span tag.
I Looked vue documentation and tried with adding this to span tag:

```html
<span class="badge" v-bind:class="'badge-success': file.uploadStatus == 'Completed'">{{file.uploadStatus}}</span>
```

I even tried some other combinations (changed text, new data property), but to no avail.

So how can i add another class to span tag when the upload status text of a file is changed?
Any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: :class should be an object. You're just missing the brackets inside the double-quotes.

Comment: Yes i missed the brackets. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

From Vue documentation:

> We can pass an object to v-bind:class to dynamically toggle classes

So, you have to do it like:

```
<span
  class="badge"
  v-bind:class="{'badge-success': file.uploadStatus == 'Completed'}"
>
  {{file.uploadStatus}}
</span>
```